# NSManagedObject using on specified queue

Tags: ios, core-data, dispatch-queue

I have a background task that is running on background queue. I need to load some NSManagedObjects in this task. I know I need to use private context but how to bound this context to my existing background queue so I can use this NSManagedObjects in my background task? Should I perform in this background task `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` or maybe I should just call from UI Thread `performBlock` on private `NSManagedObjectContext` and use queue from this context to perform any background task including loading saving NSManagedObjects and other background tasks like communicating with rest-api, etc...

I'm just not sure that I can use this queue from context to do any additional tasks not related to CoreData `NSManagedObjects`? If not how to use those `NSManagedObjects` in queue that I created for my task?

Answer (score 0):

Although queue management can always be tricky, queues spun by Core Data can run code like any other queues.

In particular, you **can** use a queue from the managed object context to do additional tasks not related to Core Data or its managed objects.  When Core Data was first released on macOS in 2005, managed objects had to be accessed on the main thread, which of course could be quite busy with other tasks.